# How to change recorded sound pitch in Windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, audio

I'm developing a Windows Phone application that should record the voice of the user and play it in different tones ( female tone , robot tone , etc.). I'm looking for an API that I can use to achieve this in C#.

I have searched but what I found was [soundtouch library](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch) but it can't be used for phone as far as I know

Comment: Maybe you can following this approach http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrisbarker/archive/2014/10/08/consuming-a-c-library-project-from-a-windows-phone-store-app.aspx